# Google sheets VLOOKUP DROP DOWN DISPLAY

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

Can someone help me with this?

As you can see, I want to display the top  10 products but must be in condition with the Name and Month dropdown. For Example, if I choose Name John and January as the month, it should display the top products which are located in Sheet 5. What formula or how should I do this? I'm thinking of using the VLOOKUP IF statement.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sejk6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDiXx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to talk about proper database structure instead solving the problem as is.

1 - you need a helper columns for employees and monthes Like so highlighted with yellow.

[image: Helper columns]

2 - also a helper table to structure data and stack each type in a column.

- In O2 cell paste this formula to stack all the tables into one table.

  `=QUERY({A2:A11,B2:D11;A2:A11,E2:G11;A2:A11,H2:J11;A2:A11,K2:M11;A13:A22,B13:D22;A13:A22,E13:G22;A13:A22,H13:J22;A13:A22,K13:M22})`

[image: Stacked ranges]

3 - To get top 10 Results of products, in Sheet2 F11 cell paste this formula.

```
=SORTN(FILTER(Sheet5!$Q$2:$R,Sheet5!$O$2:$O=$B$3,Sheet5!$P$2:$P=$B$5),10,,4,0)
```

and you will get a result like this, *red table is for verification only*.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. But how about if every month it has a different number of results. For example, January has 5 products, February has 7 products, March has 10 products, and so on. What will be the formula for the SORTN?

Comment: Replace The N of [`SORTN `](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624?hl=en) with [`COUNTA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991?hl=en) 
of the products, for example 7 product the counta of products is 7 and use it as N of SORTN function

Comment: Why can't I stack all tables into one table using the formula you provided?

Comment: Which local "language" you choose,  English,  Italian...?

Comment: You probably added mismatched ranges "row length" or using a diffrent local punctuation, I'm using ENGLISH US `,` columns join `;` column stack.